# Returning clicking parent element instead of 1 from the top - Google Tag Manager

Tags: javascript

I have a situation where I want to collect the parent `href` element while being clicked. I created a javascript custom variable in Google Tag Manager. But when I add this code:

```
function(){
    return document.getElementsByTagName('h5')[0].parentNode.href
}
```

it takes the `href` element only from the 1 (beginning from the top) not the clicked element (h5).

How i should modify it to work?

Comment: `[0]` selects the **first** H5 on the page. If this is inside an event handler, post more code, as you need to use `this` to target the clicked element

Comment: No, i look at gtm.click (the built in variable) after the click, and i add this code to custom js variable in gtm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing `document.getElementsByTagName('h5')[0]` selects the first `<h5>` element in the document (hence the 0 index). To get the right parent, you have two options:

If the function is an event handler (you are passing this function to an element's `onClick`), then modify it like so:

```
function handleClick(e) {
    return e.parentNode.href;
}
```

`e` here refers to the element that was clicked. Doing `e.parentNode` will yield you the clicked element's parent.

If this isn't an event handler, then consider giving the element you're looking for an ID to distinguish it from the others:

```
function handleClick() {
    return document.getElementById("myElem").href;
}
```

Comment: The thing is i want to do it without changing the code. Just via GTM.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
function(){ return {{Click Element}}.parentNode.href }
```

Where {{Click Element}} is a built-in GTM variable.